# Problem with rendering main body in as-pnet-core mvc

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a problem with arranging the header and footer partial views. I want these to overlap the main body view, however, it all gets rendered like in first picture, but its hould be like in second one:

[image]

Here is the '_Layout.cshtml' code:

```
    <body>
        <div name="main_area" class="main_area">
            <div name="header_meny" class="header_meny">
                @await Html.PartialAsync("_Header")
            </div>
            <div name="views_area" class="views_area">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
            <div name="footer_meny" class="footer_meny">
                @await Html.PartialAsync("_Footer")
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

and .css file:

```
.main_area {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 68px 978px 34px;
}

.header_meny {
    grid-row: 1/2;
    background: green;
}

.views_area {
    grid-row: 1/4;
    background: blue;
}

.footer_meny {
    grid-row: 3/4;
    background: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your grid rows

```
.main_area {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 68px 978px 34px;
}

.header_meny {
    grid-row: 1;
    background: green;
}

.views_area {
    grid-row: 2;
    background: blue;
}

.footer_meny {
    grid-row: 3;
    background: yellow;
}
```

Update for overlapping grids

```
.main_area {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 68px 978px 34px;
}

.header_meny {
    grid-row: 1;
    grid-column: 1;
    background: green;
}

.views_area {
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
    grid-column: 1;
    background: blue;
}

.footer_meny {
    grid-row: 3;
    grid-column: 1;
    background: yellow;
}
```

Now Grids are stacked based on the order in which they are loaded. Meaning you will have to edit your HTML as well

```
<body>
<div name="main_area" class="main_area">
    <div name="views_area" class="views_area">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    <div name="header_meny" class="header_meny">
        @await Html.PartialAsync("_Header")
    </div>
    
    <div name="footer_meny" class="footer_meny">
        @await Html.PartialAsync("_Footer")
    </div>
    
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks but this just puts the body in the middle. I want it to go across all three rows, therefore be under the header and footer.